# Как сделать такие адаптивные блоки?

Tags: html, css

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие адаптивные блоки с изображением, в таком расположении и с информацией внутри как на сайте [Яндекс Авиабилеты](https://avia.yandex.ru/) ?

Comment: А вы посмотрите код с помощью Inspect Element

Comment: Ну рассказывайте с какими проблемами вы столкнулись и что же у вас не получается? Что не позволяет вам открыть консоль и просто скопировать это у яндекса?

Comment: @Nilsan Они как-то по особому порядку адаптируются, так не получается.

Comment: @Alt_F4 Слишком много кода, путаюсь в нем

Comment: @Arcadiy что же там особого*? Блоки идут 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 ->3 и т.д. всё идёт 2 -> 3 Используйте [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) как вариант. Хотя если глянуть то сможете [увидеть](http://prntscr.com/ojxtpc) что яндекс просто добавляет класс где должно быть 2 элемента

Comment: @Nilsan Я в этом не силен, Вы можете оформить ответ с примером? Спасибо.

Comment: @Arcadiy достаточно будет если я покажу как строится эта система?

Comment: @lt_F4 Было бы лучше если бы было расположение блоком как у яндекса и с адаптированными изображениями (что-бы при любом устройст блоки фотографии внтри конструкции адаптировались под устройство)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.el_wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.img_api {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="el_wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element half">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-avia/200364/2a0000015cb1ddae583928eb050ee587ce7b/offer-desktop');"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По аналогии с яндексом

Comment: Еслив блок элемент поставить большую картинку, то она занимает и налазит на соседние блоки, изображение внутри не адаптируется.

Comment: @Arcadiy картинку нужно вставлять не через `<img /> ` а в виде `background: url();` либо использовать `object-fit:;` правда я бы не советовал так делать (но оно работает)

Comment: У меня картинки по АПИ приходят, как я их в css внесу?

Comment: @Arcadiy немного переделал ответ. Как-то так

Comment: Очень хорошо, как сделать чтобы добавлялся к классу element  через несколько изображений класс half, спрашиваю так как один на вывод апи запрос мне дает 30 картнок.

Comment: @Nilsan, чёйта "не советуете" давать картинкам `object-fit`?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 а я не знаю, ну вероятно я плохо это знаю, но кажется им менее удобно управлять чем background :-) Но судя по наводящему вопросу я ошибаюсь :-)

Comment: @Arcadiy вы просили как у яндексв - я сделал как у яндекс. Как они там выбирают и присваивают класс я ХЗ даже.

Comment: @Nilsan Переформулирую. Я могу поставить только такой код <div class="el_wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="img_api" style="background: url('Апи код изображения');"></div>
  </div></div> В процессе получения будет автоматически создано множество таких блоков с разными кодами изображений, необходимо чтобы формировалась сетка изображений как в Яндексе. То-бишь первое изображение было на весь экран в ширину, второе как у вас, третье и так далее

Comment: @Arcadiy знаете тут уже больше попахивает заявкой для биржи фриланса. Еще раз скажу как у яднекса это сделано: 1 первый элемент (на всю ширину) идёт отдельным div. потом идёт так сказать "wrapper" в котором уже код аналогичный тому что я дал в ответе. Каким образом они добавляют класс каждому 4му и 5му элементу я ХЗ (и разбираться не хочу даже). Ответ на ваш вопрос я уже дал. Но вы можете взять мой ответ и создать новый вопрос где уже спросить как эту конструкцию переделать так чтоб было без half а было с nth например или на js считалось и добавляло класс нужным элементам

Answer (score 1):

Таким образов вы можете сортировать блоки любых размеров!

```css
content {
  flex: all;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <div style=" width: 200px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div style=" width: 300px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div style=" width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div style=" width: 500px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div style=" width: 600px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
</content>
```